# Trying to reference a global variable in Typescript causes error in Aurelia project

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I have this TypeScript class which I was planning to use for refere:ncing project-specific variables

```
export class GlobalReferences{
    public baseApiUri:string

    constructor(){
        this.baseApiUri = 'http://localhost:8080/api/';
    }
}
```

However, when I try to reference it in one of my service classes like this:

```
import {GlobalReferences} from '../References/GlobalReferences';

@autoinject()
export class CategoriesService{
  http: HttpClient;
  baseApiUrl: string;
  entityCollectionName: string = 'categories';
  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient, references: GlobalReferences) {
    this.http = httpClient;
    this.baseApiUrl = references.baseApiUri;
```

then an error is thrown. Depending on where you look, the error Webpack throws is:

> ERROR in ./References/GlobalReferences.ts
>
> Module build failed: Error: Final loader didn't return a Buffer or String

But when you take a look at the error in Chrome, it is:

> ERROR [app-router] Error: No view model found in module "transactions".
>       at http://localhost:9000/aurelia.bundle.js:3664:15

However, when I assign the value directly like this, it works:

```
this.baseApiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/'
```

The question now is: How do I correctly reference the global variable?

Comment: Please check, weather your ts generated js properly or not ?

Comment: Your initial error is normally related to the transpiler failing to process an empty file. Does this disappear when you just change `references.baseApiUri` to `'http://localhost:8080/api/'`?

Comment: @thebluefox I did this and yes, the error goes away.

Comment: Try specifying `@autoinject` without the parentheses -- there's a bunch of weirdness with regards to how ES decorators work, and that's one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I needed to add and set the emitDecoratorMetadata flag to true in the tsconfig.json The autoinject() was not working properly without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these please:

File Globalreferences.ts

```
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';


@autoinject()
export class GlobalReferences {
    public baseApiUri: string

    constructor() {
        this.baseApiUri = 'http://localhost:8080/api/';
    }
}
```

Your service:

```
export class CategoriesService{
    http: HttpClient;
    baseApiUrl: string;
    entityCollectionName: string = 'categories';
    constructor(httpClient: HttpClient, references: GlobalReferences) {

        this.http = httpClient;
        this.baseApiUrl = references.baseApiUri;
    ....
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. The error is still there.

Comment: Then i would go with @thebluefox's comment that it has to do with the transpiler. And to help you part of your aureölia.json would help. I tried this with a new blank application created with aurelia cli and it just works fine!